# Redirection error for my HTML form

Tags: html, redirect, mailchimp

I have a question about integrating mailchimp in an HTML form. I have my subscribe button and I want to redirect it to my mailchimp's sub website.

```
<form action="https://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="u" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="xxxxxxxxxx">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail..." name="EMAIL" required></input>
    </form>
```

So I submit it via enter key and I redirect to my website.

http://my-website.com?u=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&id=xxxxxxxx&EMAIL=email%40email.com

But my expectation is this:

https://xxxxx.xxx.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&id=xxxxxxxx&EMAIL=email%40email.com

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure MailChimp has an option for generation HTML to add a form to your website...

Comment: Hmmmm. I don't know this feature though.